# iPhone SDK - UITextField with + Button for Contacts

Tags: iphone, button, uitextfield, contacts

In some applications like Mail, when you have a UITextField, there is a little + button to the right. When you tap it, a modal view controller comes up which you can select a phone number, address, etc from, and it will appear in the text field. I was wondering how to implement this in my own app. Thanks,
Isaac

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the plus button inside the text field, take a look at the `rightView` property of the UITextField class, which lets you put any UIView in the right-most portion of the text field.  You can put a UIButton there, as created with

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by

```
txtFldObj.rightView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];

txtFldObj.rightViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

you can also refer to this [trick](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42926-add-button-right-uitextfield.html) also

Comment: Tnks Man! ... I forgot the ViewMode ... you saved me :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having a regular UIView that contains a UITextField and a UIButton as subviews.

E.g

```
-------------------------------
| UITextField       | UIButton|
-------------------------------
```

When the button is tapped you can bring up the address book picker (or anything else) as a modal view, and when it closes update the text field as necessary.