# Textfield Connecting and Labels

Tags: ios, swift

I have always had this problem and could never figure out how to solve it. My issue is that I want to produce a similar thing as the photo: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9czNx.jpg)

I want to be able to have text fields connect like this and be able to have a 'label' on the left while still being able to input on the right. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add label to UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745453/add-label-to-uitextfield)

Comment: That question did not answer what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, I think that what you want is to have a label on the left and a textview on the right. The image you have  supplied looks like the textViews and labels reside within a UITableView controller as static cells. What they have most likely have done here is simply extended the label from the left to the centre and the textview from the right to the centre, such that each takes up half the cell (and added constraints). Then you can set the text alignment to left for the label and right for the textview. The final thing you should do is get rid of the border of the textview, which can be found in the attributes inspector and is called Border Style. You want to set it to the far left option, like this:

[image]

As the background of the cell is white and the textview's also, you shouldn't need to change it, but if you do there is an attribute for that a bit further down that you can have a play with.

Comment: So far yes this is exactly what I want and it is much easier than I had thought. Now the issue I'm dealing with is that in order to do static cells I have to use a TableViewController and with doing this it shows more than the 5 cells I need it to. Any help on that by chance?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, all I had to do was go to the tableview and inside the attribute inspector, change the style to "group" and it worked perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)