# How can I make a UITextField look like a UILabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

How can I make a `UITextField` look like the number 4.5 in the following picture:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Which text field do you mean? Do you want to enter the data into the cell directly? What about "Physik" and date date? Both will typically be implemented using a (date) picker view.

Comment: I actually only mean the one on the top, sorry.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen The date and Physik can be selected in a separated `viewController`

Comment: The one on the top, Note or 4.5 ?

Comment: @Koen Yes, the left part is a Label and the right a textfield with a placeholder text. I saw this in a app and want to do this in my app as well.

Comment: You would typically create a custom cell, add a label for the Note, auto-align it to the left, add a textfield for the value, align it to the right, connect outlets, and here you go. Dont forget to handle keyboard dismissal, keybort overlapping the table view etc.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745453/add-label-to-uitextfield/19937974#19937974

Comment: Your title and question are different. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Renetik `textContainerInset` and `contentInset` apply to `UITextView` and not `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the textfield border style like so, this way, you will have invisible borders and just put the textfield in your cell:

[image]